# Handle simultaneous requests in express on local machine from arduino

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I'm creating a local webserver (on my windows PC) for my arduino to send POST requests to. The data from these requests would then be written to Cloud Firestore via the local webserver since the Arduino cannot support HTTPS which is required for Firebase. I have the server set up using express:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const HOST_PORT = 6500;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.raw());

app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    return res.status(200).send()
})

app.post('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    return res.status(200).send()
})

app.post('/machine',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('Got body:', req.body);
    //Send to firebase here use async/await or just send the request? 
    return res.status(200).send()
})

app.listen(HOST_PORT, () => console.log(`Started server at http://localhost:${HOST_PORT}!`));
```

If three arduinos make a request to `/machine` would three instances of that functions be created? I'm wondering because I would like to know how to handle simultaneous requests on the webserver. Do I just make the call to firebase and not `await` the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nice thing about Node.js asynchronous runtime: while your /machine route awaits for a first request, it can handle other requests, no problem!

```
app.post('/machine', async (req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('Got body:', req.body);
    await firestore.doc("collection/docId").set({foo: "bar"})
    return res.status(200).send()
})
```

More info can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/about/#about-node-js)